# SQL - select distinct across multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb, distinct

I'm having trouble writing the SQL code to select distinct contacts across 8 columns from an access table. I want to only get the distinct results to not have duplicates. Below is what I've tried.

```
cmd.CommandText = "select distinct c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8 
                   from table 
                   where state IN (" + paramClause.ToString() + ")";
```

My purpose is to show this on a label with no duplicates.

Comment: You'll have to give us a bit more to go on.  Example of data, structure etc, what you expect the result to be

Comment: Please edit your question to more clearly articulate what you want. Your query as written should return distinct *rows* from the table. Do you really want a single column listing all of the distinct *values* that appear in columns [c1] through [c8]?

Comment: Hmm, okay, you want to show "this" on a label but it is still unclear what "this" is. Please show us some sample data and an example of what the final result should look like.

Comment: they're asking you to define what 'no duplicates' means to you

Comment: This may be a bit advanced, but with C#, consider using [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) to perform database queries.

Comment: @Jonesy Thanks! sry. "No duplicates" means, duplicate names that are gathered from c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8.

Comment: Is your state type string??

Answer (score 7):

If I have correctly understood, you have contacts in one or more column (from c1 to c8).

If so, try to rewrite your SQL statement like the following:

```
SELECT C1
FROM TABLE
WHERE STATE IN (...)
UNION
SELECT C2
FROM TABLE
WHERE STATE IN (...)
...
UNION
SELECT C8
FROM TABLE
WHERE STATE IN (...)
```

The UNION operator eliminates duplicates by itself.

I hope this helps you....

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select distinct c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8 
                   from table 
                   where state IN (" + paramClause.ToString() + ")";
```

But you need to wrap strings in single quotes.  I think the problem is in your WHERE clause.  Try doing this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select distinct c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8 
                   from table 
                   where state IN ('" + paramClause.ToString() + "')";
```